# Running Facebook login sample in eclipse fails

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, installation, sample

Just want to test login with Facebook. I imported the SessionLoginSample sample project and then facebookSDK project from the root package provided by Facebook, verifying that "copy project into workspace" isn't checked. (OSX Lion)

For the 2 projets, i choosed android 15 as a target version. I checked for the Java compliance Level (1.6).

1) i noticed that  the sample project didn't find support-v4 so i added it as an external Jar (from the extra/ directory of the Android SDK).

2) When i run the sample i get this :
`Could not find class 'com.facebook.samples.sessionlogin.LoginUsingCustomFragmentActivity', referenced from method com.facebook.samples.sessionlogin.SessionLoginSampleActivity$2.onClick E/dalvikvm(30852): Could not find class 'com.facebook.samples.sessionlogin.LoginUsingLoginFragmentActivity', referenced from method com.facebook.samples.sessionlogin.SessionLoginSampleActivity$3.onClick`

And when i hit one of the 3 buttons, i get an exception like this one :
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager 06-14 16:11:03.385: E/AndroidRuntime(30852): at com.facebook.Session.postActiveSessionAction(Session.java:1215) 06-14 16:11:03.385: E/AndroidRuntime(30852): at com.facebook.Session.setActiveSession(Session.java:765) 06-14 16:11:03.385: E/AndroidRuntime(30852): at com.facebook.samples.sessionlogin.LoginUsingActivityActivity.onCreate(LoginUsing‌​ActivityActivity.java:55) ...`

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: are you following https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

Comment: did you mark the facebook project as a library in your project properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so :

1) As said previouislu, you need to add the support-v4 JAR from the Facebook SDK (or from the Android SDK in Extra)

2) In the project properties of SessionLoginSample, go to Java Build Path, Order and Export You need to check the support-v4 Jar package

Answer (score 1):

Browse to select the root of your SDK folder, `facebook-android-sdk-3.0.1`. The SDK should appear in the list as 'FacebookSDK' along with all of the samples.  FacebookSDK is the library project which must be referenced in your application. import that library in your workspace.

your projct should be visible in your **workspace** following the import of FacebookSDK library , and project should correctly reference the neighboring '**FacebookSDK**' library project.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what i've got in the login sample project. I followed this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

Comment: ... but i've got the same issue

Answer (score 0):

to generate the hash key use this way.
using a seperate class and add this code and get the hash key. save it in your developer facebook site and try again.

try {
PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("your.package",
PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
md.update(signature.toByteArray());
Log.d("YOURHASH KEY:",
Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
}
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}

thanks.